# Using custom styles shows invalid characters when right-clicking a file in TOpenDialog

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-xe8, vcl-styles, topendialog

See steps below to reproduce. Works well in XE2 but not XE8.

1. Create a new VCL Forms Application - Delphi
2. Place a `TButton` and a `TOpenDialog` on the form
3. In the button `OnClick` event call `OpenDialog1.Execute`
4. Run the program, open the file dialog, and right-click on a text file => shows menu items ok
5. Go to Project/Options/Application/Appearance. Enable and choose a custom style (such as "Ruby Graphite") and recompile
6. Run the program, open the file dialog, and right-click a text file => does not show menu items correctly (invalid characters are shown)

Tested with XE8 Subscription Update 1 (and Windows upgraded from 8.1 to 10)

Comment: Which local Windows version is that?

Comment: @Rudy, Windows 10 Pro

Comment: I meant, which national version, i.e. Danish, German, US, Russian, Chinese, Dutch, French, Greek, etc. etc.

Comment: But that seems to be obsolete anyway.

Comment: Windows 10 pro, Swedish.

Comment: Ok thanks. But as I said, RRUZ's answer made knowing that obsolete anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Windows 10 introduces some internal changes in the code responsible to draw the shell popup-menus. So the VCL Style code must be modified to be compatible with Windows 10.  I just reported [this to EMB](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11682)

As workaround you can use the [VCL Styles Utils](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils) project which fixes this issue (only you need add the `Vcl.Styles.Utils.Menus` unit to your project).

Check the next Image , The left popup-menu uses the standard VCL Styles,and the right menu uses the `VCL Styles Utils` project.

[image]

Comment: This is one of the perils and risks of adopting VCL styles. Embarcadero should do a much better job of communicating this risk.

Comment: Is this related to the reverse engineering of DirectUI?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, No, the menus are drawn using a `"traditional"`  hook (SetWindowsHookEx) over the  `#32768` class.